# React native to ask access to ios photo library

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-permissions

I would like to ask the user to give access to the photo library, but only to let him give me access to all photos, not selected ones.
Is there a way to implement this?

I am using the requestPermissions from MediaLibrary
[Link](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/media-library/#usepermissionsoptions)

Any help would be appreciated! :)

I could not find it in the docs or anywhere else for that matter

Comment: Please, take a look at this doc: https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions. It's the most used lib to work with permissions in react-native. I think that using it will solve your problem.